# From 10 numbers, select 2 number with equal probability

Tags: probability

I have a basic understanding of probability. The above statement is written inside an algorithm example. But I am stuck with the term "Equal Probability". There is no specific discussion in Google. So far I got few concepts but not sure I was right or wrong.

Concept 1: "equal probability" is a sampling method

Concept 2: "equal probability means "equal chance of being selected"

if concept 2 is right,

example 1: Suppose we have 10 numbers. 1,4,3,5,1,3,1,6,9,4

4 and 3 is perfect sampling with equal probability.

5 and 6 is perfect sampling with equal probability.

1 and 4 is not perfect sampling with equal probability.

1 and 5 is not perfect sampling with equal probability.

Update: as per the suggestion here I am uploading the picture from the slide:

[image]

Let me rephrase my questions:

1) Did I describe the example 1: correctly?

2) How did they construct probability of failure as 1/(2^100) ? ( may not be related to original question, but if someone can guide, that will help )

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  Naively, I would say that sampling with equal probability meant that you choose an element from your list uniformly at random.  Thus if you had $11$ balls numbered as you have written, I choose two balls from the collection uniformly (so that each pair is equally likely to be chosen)...leaving the question of replacement unaddressed.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: It would be useful if you could point us to where you are seeing this. If it is not an online source, a picture will also help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough way of stating that there is a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) and that they are "independent" in the sence that their outcome does not affect the problem. In other words, the question is saying that $E_i$, where $E_i$ is drawing a number from $\{1, \dots, 10\}$ are [independently identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables).